# Debug 10.6 Project into 10.5?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, debugging

Can I debug a 10.6 project into a 10.5? I have computers at school that are still 10.5 and I need to downgrade it so I can run my program on their computers.

Thanks,,

Kevin

Comment: Do you want to *build your project on* 10.5, or *run and debug its build product (application)* on 10.5?  If the latter, look in the Xcode documentation for "Remote Debugging."

Answer (score 5):

I assume you mean you want to load your Xcode project onto the school computers.

First, are you using any 10.6 specific APIs? If so, you can't run your app on 10.5.

Right click on your project and Get Info. Then check some things:

1. General->Project Format: Is this an Xcode version that will be compatible with the school computer? 10.5 will be an Xcode 3.1.x system (pretty sure about this, though it could be 3.0.x)
2. Build->Base SDK. Is this set to 10.5?

If those look good, you should be set.

Comment: Kevin: That didn't answer any of the questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you build against the 10.6 SDK, you can only run on 10.6 and higher.

If you build against the 10.5 SDK, you can run on 10.5, 10.6 and higher.